# cannot send email from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net

It works fine for a particular email address, but rest of the emails dont works..following error shows up:

```
Server Error in '/RealTimeArsenicDataVisualizer' Application.
Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: From address not verified - see http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/manage/sendfrom-07.html
```

my code:

```
 System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.co.in", 587);

        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
     client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(emailid, password);

            client.Port = 587;

            client.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.co.in";

            client.EnableSsl = false;

            object userstate = msg;

            client.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to below:

```
client.Port = 465;

client.Host = " smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
client.EnableSsl = true;
```